# Подключение шрифтов в Sass

Tags: javascript, css, angular2, sass

У меня возникла проблема. Я подключил все шрифты в `fonts.sass`(размещен в корне папки `app`) но их не видно с файла `header.component.sass`. Сами шрифты я поместил в папку `assets/fonts` и сейчас получаю вот такую ошибку:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/app/header/header.component.sass
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError: X:\projects\BranD\src\app\fonts.sass:15:9: Can't resolve '.../assets/fonts/LatoBold/lato-bold.eot' in 'X:\projects\BranD\src\app\header'

  13 | @font-face {
  14 |     font-family: 'latobold';
> 15 |     src: url('.../assets/fonts/LatoBold/lato-bold.eot');
     |         ^
  16 |     src: url('.../assets/fonts/LatoBold/lato-bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), {
  17 |          url:'.../assets/fonts/LatoBold/lato-bold.woff' format('woff'),

 @ ./src/app/header/header.component.ts 22:21-55
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0 ./src/main.ts
```

Comment: Возможно на 3 точки ругаеться `url('.../` ?

Comment: Менял,не помогло

Comment: Вы используете sass или scss?

Comment: sass.через ng new BranD --style=sass

Comment: Попробуйте поудалять {} и ; ,  у sass руби синтаксис, там нет должно их быть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удалите строку `src: url('.../assets/fonts/LatoBold/lato-bold.eot');`.

Не компилируется из-за дублирования свойства `src`. Вы в курсе вообще, зачем там это указано? Это фикс для IE 8. Не знаю, какая версия `AngularJS` у вас, но начиная с версии 2.0 он не поддерживает IE 8.

Да и форматы шрифтов у вас старые. Никто уже не использует такие. Сейчас нужны три формата: `woff2`, `woff` и `ttf`.

Вот вам пример правильного и современного подключения шрифтов:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    src: local('Lato Bold'), local('Lato-Bold'),
         url('../fonts/latobold.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/latobold.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/latobold.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```